# eclipse debugging - don't want to see classes that aren't in project

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a beginner to programming and maybe this is a basic question but I recently recieved an android application.

the person who wrote the application is no longer working here and I can't reach him at the moment. 
So basically I want to understand how the mechanism of the app works by taking his code and debugging it (in eclipse) line by line and see what the flow is.

I started debugging but during debugging it jumped to classes that aren't even in the project, maybe resource classes and stuff like that.

so I have seen how to perform step filtering in the preferences, but it still showing me classes that aren't in the project.

I know this because it jumps to classes that I dont have the sources for .
I get "source not found"

what should I do?

Comment: @SiddharthVyas check tags....

Comment: last comment wasn't for you. About your question, is it SDK class?

Comment: You are stepping through the Android APIs.

Comment: ok. how do I filter these steps??

Answer (score 0):

All classes are in the project or are dependencies of the project, the problem is you are missing their source code. Try to attach it by clicking on

[image]

If you don't want to see certain classes, use step filters explain here:
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-usestepfilters.htm

Comment: You cant. You have to keep in mind which classes you actually have coded OR you actually have source for.

Comment: this is an example :

http://s1.postimg.org/64egphidr/Capture.jpg

ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity : what is this class? its not in the my source classes and I don't want the debug to step into that!